# How to update database from server

Tags: android, database

I am making an Android application, but i have a problem. I have no idea what is the best way to update the database in the client application from my server (if the user click the "check for update" button). How should i set the current database version in client-side so that i can try to compare with the latest database version in server ? how should i check from server if there is any new database update ? should i use PHP / java server ?

My Case :
User installed my app that come with an sqlite database version 1.0
But later, i updated the sqlite database to version 2.0 and upload it to server (i havent think about what kind of server will i use, any idea (java or php) ?)
and i want when the user click "check for updates", the app will check for the latest database version, if the latest db version is 2.0 (which is >1.0) then it will download and replace the old sqlite db (1.0).
How should i set the sqlite database version in client-side (Android) and compare it with the latest version in server-side?

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: I assume you want to update the data in the database, not the actual database itself (because you're asking *How should i set the current database version*). PHP or java? That's your decision. Both languages / techniques will do the job...

Comment: i edited the title. i did mean to update the database itself, not the data. Thanks though

Comment: the question is still a little vague ... you may have more accurate responses of you add a clear and detailed description of what you are trying to achieve with some example

Comment: i added some more explanation of what i want to achieve. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733974/how-to-update-database-from-server/7734234#7734234)...

If your problem is that simple I would suggest to do following:

- Request your server for latest newest database state via HTTP (it could return a timestamp or database version) e.g. with `http://www.yourserver.tld/?dbversion`
- If your local database is less then the returned timestamp or version you pull the database from server e.g. with `http://www.yourserver.tld/?dbget`
- After that you persist the timestamp or version (for example in a shared preference)

Your server always knows which version is the newest and could update the returned timestamp or the returned (and incremented) version number...

*PHP or Java*: I would recommend PHP for such a simple task (also because every webspace offers that option). I would realize that by a simple GET request (like demonstrated before). Java is just overkill (but still possible).

Comment: Great ! i think i will do it your way !
Thanks